# Control flow graph

Tags: control-flow-graph

> consider this control flow graph.  we need to find total independents
>   liner path. when we use  "V(g) = e-n+2
>         = 7-6+2
>         = 3"
>
> but if i count manually i got 4 independents liner path.  paths are:
>
> > "0=>1=>3=>5",    "0 => 1 => 3 => 4 => 5",   "0 => 2 =>3=> 5",   "0=> 2 => 3 => 4 => 5"
>
> why this both value are different?

[**Control flow graph here**][1]

> > [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRBmD.png

Answer (score 0):

For calculating McCabe complexity, you need to find edges and nodes. The first formula will be:

```
v(F) = edge - node + 2
```

The second formula is:

```
v(F) = # of decision nodes + 2
```

Note that # of decision nodes also named as predicate nodes.

Now there are 6 nodes (circles) and 7 edges (arrows) in your graph.

Therefore McCabe complexity will be = `v(F) = 7 - 6 + 2 = 3`.

The second way to solve is:

There are two predicate nodes (decision nodes) `0` and `3` so `v(F) = 2 + 1 = 3`.